# filter behaviour - kotlin

Tags: kotlin, filter

Why does this code give the result of "[]" if "J" is given?
How does "filter" work in it?

```
var letter = readLine()!![0]
val names = arrayOf("John", "David", "Amy", "James", "Amanda")`
val res = names.filter{ it.substring(0,1).equals(letter)  }`
println(res)`
```

Comment: You're comparing type `String` with type `Char` and always get `false`. Try to write your filter condition like this: `it.substring(0,1).equals(letter.toString())`. Or like this: `it[0].equals(letter)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) returns all the elements of the list that satisfies the given predicate.

In this case, the predicate is `it.substring(0,1).equals(letter)`, where `it` is a given element of the list. As a matter of fact, this can never be satisfied, because `it.substring` returns a `String`, but `letter` is a `Char`. You are comparing objects of completely different types.

Assuming you want to find all the names that start with `letter`, you should compare the same types - get the first letter of `it` *as a `Char`* using `[0]` or `first()` etc.

```
val res = names.filter { it.first() == letter }
```

Additional notes:

- it is more idiomatic to compare with `==`, rather than `equals`.
- `letter` can be a `val`, instead of `var`.
- Since Kotlin 1.6, you can use [`readln()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/readln.html) instead of `readLine()` to avoid the `!!` operator.

Alternatively, as lukas.j suggested, use [`startsWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/starts-with.html):

```
val res = names.filter { it.startsWith(letter) }
```

Comment: _names.filter { it.startsWith(letter) }_ would also be an option, as one of the _startsWith_ overloads is taking a _Char_.